# Cant Create New partition after uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu before today. I tried to delete a partition of Ubuntu from windows 7. I deleted the swap partition first then, then I deleted the `/home` partition.
After that the free space of both got combined. I tried to create new partition from it, 
but an error occurred:

> there is not enough space available on the disk to complete this operation

Hence I'm unable to create a partition. How do I to fix that? I even tried to create one from windows 7 disk too, but got same error.

[image]

Comment: Try to create partition as logical instead of primary on free space.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have 4 primary partitions on a single hard drive in Windows, and in that screenshot there I see 4 plus the free space.  If you would like to extend partitions, combine them, etc., then you'll have to use something like GParted.

You can download GParted at: http://gparted.org/

Comment: but i had this partition bfore and now i lost after installation of ubuntu, thats not a answer u said that i can only have 4 partition?